# Read json with multiple levels into a DataFrame [python]

Tags: json, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

I have json files in this generic format:

```
{"attribute1": "test1",
 "attribute2": "test2",
 "data": {
      "0": 
         {"metadata": {
             "timestamp": "2022-08-14"},
         "detections": {
             "0": {"dim1": 40, "dim2": 30},
             "1": {"dim1": 50, "dim2": 20}}},
      "1": 
         {"metadata": {
             "timestamp": "2022-08-15"},
         "detections": {
             "0": {"dim1": 30, "dim2": 10},
             "1": {"dim1": 100, "dim2": 80}}}}}
```

These json files refer to the collection of measurements through a 3D camera. The upper levels in the key `data` correspond to frames and each frame has its own `metadata` and can have multiple `detections` objects, each object with its own dimensions (here represented by `dim1` and `dim2`). I want to convert this type of json file to a `pandas` DataFrame in the following format:

| timestamp | dim1 | dim2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 2022-08-14 | 40 | 30 |
| 2022-08-14 | 50 | 20 |
| 2022-08-15 | 30 | 10 |
| 2022-08-15 | 100 | 80 |

So, any fields in `metadata` (here I only added `timestamp` but there could be several) must be repeated for each entry in the `detection` key.

I can convert this type of json to a `pandas` DataFrame, but it requires multiple steps and for loops within a single file to concatenate everything at the end. I have also tried `pd.json_normalize` and playing with the arguments `record_path`, `meta` and `max_level` but so far I was not able to, in a few steps, convert this type of json to a DataFrame. Is there a clean way to do this?

Comment: I think json is not valid.

Comment: @jezrael thank you for pointing out. I have corrected the json format. I run this code through an online json validator and it was validated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use nested dictioanry comprehension for flatten `values` and merge subdictionaries, last pass to DataFrame constructor:

```
json = {"attribute1": "test1",
 "attribute2": "test2",
 "data": {
      "0": 
         {"metadata": {
             "timestamp": "2022-08-14"},
         "detections": {
             "0": {"dim1": 40, "dim2": 30},
             "1": {"dim1": 50, "dim2": 20}}},
      "1": 
         {"metadata": {
             "timestamp": "2022-08-15"},
         "detections": {
             "0": {"dim1": 30, "dim2": 10},
             "1": {"dim1": 100, "dim2": 80}}}}}

L = [{**x['metadata'], **y} for x in json['data'].values() 
                            for y in x['detections'].values()]

df = pd.DataFrame(L)
print (df)
    timestamp  dim1  dim2
0  2022-08-14    40    30
1  2022-08-14    50    20
2  2022-08-15    30    10
3  2022-08-15   100    80
```

Comment: Thank you. I like this approach as I can add extra attributes in "metadata" if needed and it will still work.

Answer (score 1):

I think a good solution could be:

```
data = [dict(d1, **{'detections': list(d1['detections'].values())}) 
        for d1 in d['data'].values()]
#data = list(map(lambda d1: dict(d1, 
#                **{'detections': list(d1['detections'].values())}),
#               d['data'].values()))

print(data)
df = \
pd.json_normalize(data, 'detections', [['metadata', 'timestamp']])\
.rename({'metadata.timestamp': 'timestamp'}, axis=1)
print(df)

#[{'metadata': {'timestamp': '2022-08-14'}, 'detections': [{'dim1': 40, 'dim2': 30}, {'dim1': 50, 'dim2': 20}]}, {'metadata': {'timestamp': '2022-08-15'}, 'detections': [{'dim1': 30, 'dim2': 10}, {'dim1': 100, 'dim2': 80}]}]
#   dim1  dim2   timestamp
#0    40    30  2022-08-14
#1    50    20  2022-08-14
#2    30    10  2022-08-15
#3   100    80  2022-08-15
```

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to address my question. Your solution works with the example that I provided but then it if I try to add more metadata fields, it will fail raising the error  ```TypeError: string indices must be integers```. I just adapted the code like this (added latitude field in metadata):

```pd.json_normalize(data_values, 'detections', [['metadata', "timestamp", "latitude"]]).rename({'metadata.timestamp': 'timestamp','metadata.latitude': 'latitude'}, axis=1) ```